# Why does `clockTime` not seem to work for benchmarking, in Idris?

Tags: benchmarking, idris

There are probably libraries to do this (although I haven't found any), I'm actually looking to measure the time a function takes to run in Idris. The way I've found is by using `clockTime` from `System` and differentiating between before and after a function runs. Here is an example code:

```
module Main

import Data.String
import System

factorial : Integer -> Integer
factorial 0 = 1
factorial 1 = 1
factorial n = n * factorial (n - 1)

main : IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs

    case args of
        [self ] => putStrLn "Please enter a value"
        [_, ar] => do
            case parseInteger ar of
                Just a => do

                    t1 <- clockTime
                    let r = factorial a
                    t2 <- clockTime

                    let elapsed = (nanoseconds t2) - (nanoseconds t1)

                    putStrLn $ "fact(" ++ show a ++ ") = "
                                       ++ show r ++ " in "
                                       ++ (show elapsed) ++ " ns"

                Nothing => putStrLn "Not a valid number"
```

To avoid Idris optimising the program by already evaluating the factorial, I just asked that the program be called with an argument.

This code doesn't work though: no matter what numbers I enter, such as `10000`, Idris always returns 0 nanoseconds, which makes me quite sceptical, even just allocating a bigint takes time. I compile with `idris main.idr -o main`.

What am I doing wrong in my code? Is `clockTime` not a good plan for benchmarks?

Comment: Idris 1 is no longer being developed. You should switch to Idris 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idris 1 is no longer being maintained.
In Idris 2, [clockTime](https://www.idris-lang.org/docs/idris2/current/base_docs/docs/System.Clock.html#System.Clock.clockTime) can be used.

```
clockTime : (typ : ClockType) -> IO (clockTimeReturnType typ)
```

An example of its use for benchmarking can be found within the Idris2 compiler, [here](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris2/blob/094a9ab06d68bea216d892058c5e323738cab858/src/Core/Context/Log.idr#L104-L120).

Comment: Even though Idris 1 is no longer maintained, I find it strange that a function of its standard lib just doesn't work. Thanks for the remark anyway, I guess that solves my problem.